# Where do I ask hardware-related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Could anyone tell me where to ask question about hardware? Such as network interface card?

Comment: Best bet would be http://serverfault.com or possibly http://superuser.com for PC related issues.  Read the FAQ on each site before posting to ensure that your question is valid.

Comment: You should go here: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Why was this migrated here?!? I voted for Off-Topic :-/

Comment: @Barry Only needs at least 3 votes for migration for that to happen ♪

Comment: @grace - even so, why send it here? makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Barry Because Meta Stack Overflow is the place to ask where questions belong on the Stack Exchange Network. It's not always intuitive where something belongs, and we operate as something of a central hub that can answer basic confusion on this topic.

Comment: As the linked duplicate post states above; Meta Super User is the place to go for Hardware Questions.  http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can ask questions regarding computer hardware over at [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/faq). If your question concerns server hardware, there is an amount of crossover with [Serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/faq).

**Update** As of 2018, [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is in beta.

Comment: At superuser they do not want this kind of question. After reading this comment I [posted a question](http://superuser.com/q/878235/260809), but they want to close it as off-topic.

Comment: @Scz Shopping questions are generally off topic across the whole of Stack Exchange, for the reasons given on your question.

Comment: I, too, may be having [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/1262059/are-there-any-large-4k-tvs-on-the-market-which-have-displayport-ports) closed as off-topic. I asked whether 4K TVs with DisplayPort exist. Denying recommendations on StackExchange seems like a strange policy since there's a [SE site dedicated just to software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There is not a Beta Stack Exchange for hardware questions https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rippledj there certainly does apper to be?

Comment: There IS a Beta Stack Exchange for hardware questions hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com